# How guided filter preserve strong edge?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, filtering

I am looking for a method that can preserve strong edge in presence of noise. I found that guided filter as best choice. However, I don't understand why it can preserve edge comparison with other method such as Gaussian. Could you explain it help me:

1. What is strong edge? How to preserve it by using guided filter?

In the paper, the author explained such as
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For edge-preserving filters, the Kuwahara filter is a good place to start. Once you've read about it, implemented it, and tested it a bit you'll be better prepared to consider other techniques.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuwahara_filter

"Edge preserving" means that edge gradients (e.g. the transition from dark to light) are not weakened [much] by the filter. For example, if you had an image of a box, but if the image had a lot of speckle noise, then an edge-preserving filter will eliminate or reduce the effect of the noise without blurring the edges of the box.

First consider what a box with strong edges looks like in a noise-free image.

[image: clean box with no noise]

If a Gaussian filter is applied, then the edges of the box will become blurred.

[image: clean image with Gaussian blur]

Edge-preserving filters address problems in which strong edges appear in a noise image. For example, we can add noise to the image of the box.
[image: sharp box edges in presence of noise]

Simply using a Gaussian kernel will reduce the noise intensity, but will also blur the edges of the box.

[image: blurred box edges after denoising]

An edge-preserving filter reduces noise, but minimizes the blurring effect on the box edges.

[image: sharp box edges after edge-preserving denoising]

That last image is one I created in GIMP, and is **not** from an edge-preserving filter, but it illustrates the concept: the box edges remain relatively strong even after an edge-preserving filter is applied to reduce noise. At the moment I don't have access to my implementations of various edge-preserving filters.

Comment: Did you consider the Guided filter? Which one is better?

Comment: Consider your application needs. There's no "better" algorithm for all applications, though some algorithms may be used more widely. The authors of the paper on the guided filter give some examples on the very first page: (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jiansun/papers/GuidedFilter_ECCV10.pdf). Kaiming He mentions this: "Try the guided filter in any situation when the bilateral filter works well. The guided filter is much faster and sometimes (though not always) works better." (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kahe/eccv10/ )

Comment: Thank Rethunk for your answer. I just want to know one more thing is that "what is meaning of edge preserving?" Please look at my question and could you make it more clear explanation or give me some example what is edge preserving in that sense.

Comment: I edited my answer and added some images. I didn't have much time, so I created some fake images. That's as much as I can do to help at this point. Good luck!